# Find My iPhone: Cancel "Lost mode Pending"

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Is there a way to cancel **Lost Mode Pending** status of my iPhone?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If you [remove the device from your account](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702) while it's offline, any pending actions for the device are canceled.

[Apple Support - If your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch is lost or stolen - What if your device is off or offline?](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201472)

Keep in mind the impact of removing the device from your account — you will no longer be able to use Find My iPhone and Activation Lock will be disabled.